# Regex - require some characters and allow only some additional?

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5, whitelist

I want to validate usernames in PHP and check them with a regular expression. They should contain at least 2 'real' characters, like `A`, `Ä`, `s`, `1` or `5`, but some others like `.` or `_` or a whitespace should be allowed , too. The position of the required characters does not matter.

This is what I had so far, and does unfortunately also allow `...` as username:

```
preg_match('/^[\pL\pN\s-+_.]+$/u', $value)
```

I want to allow only certain characters. No `<`, or `#` for example.
How can I do this?

Comment: **Must** it be containing `.`, `-`, white space? or it is optional?

Comment: no they should be optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see...

- At least two letters/numbers: `^(?:.*?[\p{L}\p{N}]){2}`
- Other characters allowed: `^[-+.\w ]+$`

Let's combine that together, and we get:

```
^(?=(?:.*?[\p{L}\p{N}]){2})[-+.\w ]+$
```

I used a *lookahead* for the part that checks there are at least 2 required characters, and just put everything else in the main part of the pattern. Together, this lets you check two different conditions over the same input.

Comment: could you explain this part `?:.*?` ?

Comment: @haheute `(?=...)` is a lookahead, `(?:...)` is a non capturing group `.*?` matches everything non greedy. Now you have the search terms and you should be able to figure out yourself what each prat really does :-)

Comment: @haheute, andlrc gave you the answer - I'll just point you to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mM7aE1/1) which can break apart any PCRE pattern you throw at it if you're struggling with some feature (look at the *explanation* part).